# security rules problems with firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

here I have a little problem concerning the firestore security rules

I create an online notepad and I would like these notes to be accessible only by certain users identified by a groupId. I specify that I have specified a groupId to my cities also in order to be able to match my identified users to my identified cities.
In terms of my code, everything is fine but it is at the level of the firestore rules that I do not succeed.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users /{documents = **} {
        allow create,read,write : if request.auth != null
    }
    match /cities/{city}/citees/{citee}{
        allow read : if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.groupId == get(/databases/$(database)/documents/cities/$(city).data.groupId
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not 100% clear to me what is your functional goal. Can you explain it in a more precise way (whith diagrams?) and in particular the difference between the groupId linked to cities and the groupId of "certain users".

Comment: Of course.
Only users with the same groupId as the city would have access to it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a syntax error in it. Seems to be missing `)` after `$(city)`. It should be like this:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users /{documents = **} {
        allow create,read,write : if request.auth != null
    }
    match /cities/{city}/citees/{citee}{
        allow read : if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.groupId == get(/databases/$(database)/documents/cities/$(city)).data.groupId
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think I understood, I need to be able to retrieve the variables from my users database but it seems to me that when I am in the cities match, I cannot access them because I receive an error message: " Calling the [get] function with an incorrect path: / databases / (default) / documents / users / "

Comment: Are you sure you have `users` collection in your Firestore? Can you add  database structure to the question?

Answer (score 0):

yes, I have access to the database because when I try to recover my "uers" collection alone, I can do it